# Make temporary directory with POSIX.1-2001

Tags: c, posix, stdio

A program I'm working on needs a temporary directory. However, I would like to stick to POSIX.1-2001. With this constraint, is there a way around using `tmpnam`? I know the security problems, but that isn't a concern of mine. The reason for me not to use it is that it is marked obsolete in POSIX.1-2008. At what point will obsolete functions be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In POSIX 2001 (2004), you'll probably have to use [`mktemp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mktemp.html) to create the name and then `mkdir()` to create a directory with that name.  This could lead to TOCTOU (time-of-check, time-of-use) problems with symlinks etc.  However, with that said, the `mktemp()` function does not appear in POSIX 2008 (so functions are removed sometimes), but it is probably in the library of every system still.  The `tmpnam()` function is present in both versions of POSIX.

In POSIX 2008, you'd be able to use [`mkdtemp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdtemp.html) instead, which has security advantages.

Comment: OP is mistaken that there is any security problem with `mktemp` or `tmpnam`. Either is fine to use. What's not fine is opening (any!) file for creation without `O_EXCL`, but that's not an issue to begin with if using `mkdir` instead of `open`/`creat`.

Comment: The security problem is that it's a PITA to have to regenerate a name if the first one exists by the time you use it.  Linux (`glibc`) also objects if you use `mktemp()`.  That's something you have to live with if you can't use `mkstemp()` or `mkdtemp()` and are not willing to write your own analogues of those.

Comment: I don't see why `do tmpnam(...); while (mkdtemp(...) && errno==EEXIST);` or similar is a PITA.

Comment: It would be `mkdir` not `mkdtemp` if you’re quick

Comment: It’s longer-winded than simply calling a function that does the job right.  It needs to be packaged into a function, and needs appropriate error handling and probably a limit on the number of attempts, and you have to reset the template after each failure, and generally isn’t as convenient as have the pre-packaged function to do the job for you.

Comment: Yes, I meant `mkdir`, and yes I did forget the need to reset the template (not needed with `tmpnam` though).

Comment: With `tmpnam()`, you have no control over where the file is created. POSIX provides `tempnam()` — which might itself use `tmpnam()` — to specify a directory and file template. It quickly becomes simpler to write your own code that'll do the job the way you think it should be done. On some versions of Linux, you can pass `mkdir()` a name which consists of a symlink identifying a target directory plus a name within that directory and it 'works'.  I used: `mkdir junk1; ln -s junk1 junk2` in the shell, then `char template[] = "junk2/pqr.XXXXXX"; mktemp(template); mkdir(template);` and it worked.